# Add "namespace" to serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers, serialization

I have `User` model existing in my db, however I would like to return json response with `active_model_serializers` gem in which `user` attributes are encapsulated/nested in `player` namespace which DOES NOT exist in db (say it is virtual and this is arbitrary expected response).

Instead of:

```
{
    "email": "some@mail.com",
    "first_name": "Hey",
    "last_name": "Hoo",
    "birthdate": "1540-05-05",
    "phone_number": "856539571"
}
```

I would like to have:

```
{
    "player":
    {
        "email": "some@mail.com",
        "first_name": "Hey",
        "last_name": "Hoo",
        "birthdate": "1540-05-05",
        "phone_number": "856539571"
    }
}
```

Comment: may be have a look at [ActiveType](https://github.com/makandra/active_type), look at `nests_one` and use that in serializers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided before works as well, but in the end I used slightly different approach. Turned out that aside `player` there should be another json, let's say `team`, which makes final response look like this:

```
{
    "player": 
    {
        "email": "some@mail.com",
        ...
    },
    "team":
    {
        "name": "Fancy Team",
        ...
    }
}
```

What I actually did was to define exact json that I wanted to use, like this:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveRecord::Serializer
    attributes :player
    attributes :team

    def player
        {
            email: object.email,
            ...
        }
    end

    def team
        { 
            name: object.name,
            ...
        }
    end
end
```

If I used `root` option in `render json:`, whole serializer would be encapsulated in this name. Sorry for not clearing it at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

When Nwocha's answer is correct I will add more details to it.

As for [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/rendering.md) says:

Overriding the resource root only applies when using the JSON adapter.

Normally, the resource root is derived from the class name of the resource being serialized. e.g. `UserPostSerializer.new(UserPost.new)` will be serialized with the root `user_post` or `user_posts` according the adapter collection pluralization rules.

When using the JSON adapter in your initializer (`ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json`), or passing in the adapter in your render call, you can specify the root by passing it as an argument to render. For example:

```rb
  render json: @user_post, root: "admin_post", adapter: :json
```

This will be rendered as:

```rb
  {
    "admin_post": {
      "title": "how to do open source"
    }
  }
```

**Note**: *the Attributes adapter (default) does not include a resource root. You also will not be able to create a single top-level root if you are using the :json_api adapter*.

Answer (score 1):

Within the UserSerializer class, define the root attribute. E.g:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  root :player

  ...
end
```

Comment: I have `UserSerializer` defined exactly as you did, but it throws `undefined_method` on `root` when I call it.

Comment: what version of AMS are you using?

Comment: In this project it is `active_model_serializers (0.10.10)`